# How to set a name header for a lambda function within groupby in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the following code to groupby and count/sum etc.

```
groups = df[df['isTrade'] == 1].groupby('dateTime')                         
grouped = (groups.agg({'tradeBid': [np.sum,lambda x: (x > 0).sum()],}))
```

The output is giving me:

```
tradeBid    tradeBid
sum <lambda>

79  46
7   6
4   4
20  6
```

How can I change the output's header ( so my end user will know what is this data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can provide names like this:

```
groups.agg({
  'tradeBid': [
    ('sum', np.sum),
    ('other', lambda x: (x > 0).sum())
  ]
})
```

It used to be you could use a `dict` instead of a list of 2-tuples, but that is now deprecated (probably because the ordering of the columns is then arbitrary).

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @ayhan: The docs say `agg()` accepts "dict of column names -> functions (or list of functions)" but does not say that a list of 2-tuples is an acceptable substitute.  Nor does it say that using a dict now results in a deprecation warning.  But I know that many things in NumPy/Pandas which could use a dict can also use a list of (name, value) tuples.  So I tried it and it worked.  So no, it's not documented.  :)

Comment: Yeah I have never seen it so I thought maybe they added this after deprecating dict renaming but it seems it was always possible. Good to know. :)